# onload to trigger a button click (WP7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, click, loaded

I need to trigger a application bar onclick method onload of the page. I have the following methods.

```
 public MapPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MapPage_Loaded;
        }
        void MapPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            abc_Checked(null, null);
            efc_Checked(null, null);

            String selected = amenties[0];
            httpRequest(selected);


         }
```

This is the method i would like to call in the onload.

```
 private void clearGraphics_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Can someone guide me on how to correctly run this clearGraphics_click on load? I tried clearGraphics_click(null,null); It wont work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Please state the problem.

Comment: please make it clear, what did you mean doesn't work? was it error, or you didn't see *the expected result*, and what is it *the expected result* exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a Visible="False" on the graphic layers hides the points that is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sending the same objects in the `MapPage_Loaded` function? Like this:

```
clearGraphics_click(sender,e);
```

Comment: tired, it just wont click it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put logic in `clearGraphics_click` to a separate function then call that function in `MapPage_Loaded`.
2. just put this `clearGraphics_click(null, null);` in `MapPage_Loaded` if you don't make use of the two parameters in the code.

And how do you mean *"it won't work"*?

Comment: wont work meaning it wont clear the graphic on the map, while i manuelly click the method of clearGraphics_click, it cleared. But when put on this.loaded. It wont work

Comment: kinda weird, assuming you don't use those 2 methods parameter inside the method code, there shouldn't be any difference wherever it called. Maybe somehow (asynchoronous execution or sth) your code populated the graphic after calling `clearGraphics_click`, not very sure

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WP7 programming, but try adding `this.Loaded += clearGraphics_click;` after `this.Loaded += MapPage_Loaded;` in the constructor